# "I guess Americans are hated a lot of places." What's wrong with this sentence exactly?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

From *Cat's Cradle* (Vonnegut).

> "The highest possible form of treason," said Minton, "is to say that Americans aren't loved wherever they go, whatever they do. Claire tried to make the point the American foreign policy should recognize hate rather than imagine love."
>
> "**I guess Americans *are* hated a lot of places**."
>
> "*People* are hated a lot of places. Claire pointed out in her letter...."

How would you describe the grammar in this sentence? Is there a *zero copula* equivalent for prepositions?

Comment: I can't make any comment on the grammar in play one way or the other (I'm not qualified), but I can tell you that simply reading the sentence naively, nothing rings wrong about it to my ear. It might seem a little smoother phrased "hated [in] a lot of places", or it might not. Really, it seems fine as it stands to me.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. There's no rule saying we always *have* to use a preposition wherever possible. This one seems similar to, say, [*I have been many places*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22been+many+places%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (which is in fact *less* common with the preposition ***to***).

Comment: In your title you assume something _is_ wrong, and none of us (so far) agree. What do _you_ think the problem with it is?

Comment: It seems the word ***places***, in phrases like *other places*, *many places* and *a lot of places*, can behave like an adverb. *"People speak funny other places*" and *"people walk fast a lot of places"* sound fine. But *"people speak funny Boston"* and *"people walk fast New York"* both need the *in*. And in fact, just by itself, *"I've been places"* is okay.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence, grammatically, is perfectly fine. It sounds better as "...are hated **in** a lot of places." but that's just personal opinion.